# Какие грамматические ошибки есть в предложении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, типы-ошибок

С тобой мы будем рядом, задаю вопрос тебе взглядом,
Ты отвечаешь, если нет, то ты будешь мне братом...

Есть ли ошибка в оборотах речи (грамматическая ошибка)?
Или так говорить вообще нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

Я это понял так:
"С тобой мы будем рядом?" - задаю вопрос тебе взглядом,
Если ответишь мне:"Нет", то ты будешь мне братом...

Answer (score 0):

Я грамматических ошибок не вижу. Единственная корявость в видо-временной соотнесённости: задаю - отвечаешь, если нет, то  будешь. Но конструкция разговорная, это вполне возможно. Отвечаешь - настоящее в значении будущего времени.

Вся беда здесь в пунктуации. Чтобы привести фразу в порядок, нужно расставить знаки препинания, тогда проявится смысл. Возможны варианты.

1.*"С тобой мы будем рядом?" - задаю вопрос тебе взглядом. Ты отвечаешь. Если "Нет", то ты будешь мне братом...*

2.*"С тобой мы будем рядом?" - задаю вопрос тебе взглядом,ты отвечаешь если "Нет", то ты будешь мне братом...*Это с инверсией. Но я поняла, это вроде как попытка стиха - в поэзии это фигура речи.

Но если это стихотворение, желательна всё-таки правка основательная. Например:

"С тобой мы будем рядом?" - я вопрошаю взглядом.

Коль "нет" - мне будешь братом...

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит как диалог, но непонятно, где слова героев. От этого зависит постановка знаков препинания. Мое предположение:

"С тобой мы будем рядом?" — задаю вопрос тебе взглядом.
Ты отвечаешь: "Если нет, то ты будешь мне братом".